# Row goes over padding

Tags: html, css

I want to place a row inside a parent div, which has padding, but the row goes over padding. Overflow hidden seems to allow it to go over padding. Does it have anyting to do with the row being flex? How could I solve it?

LINK TO DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-eibbr9?file=App.tsx

[image]
[image]

HTML:

```
          <div className="bg-wrapper" >
          <div className="row align-items-center" >
      <div className="col-lg-6">
        ...
      </div>

      <div className="col-lg-6">
          ...
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: url(../images/shape/bg2.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 82px 50px 89px;
  min-width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding overflow: auto to a div bellow bg-wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
.bg-wrapper {
    height: 400px;
}
```

You set `height: 400px;` to the `.bg-wrapper`, but the child has a height of `482px` that's why there is an overflow. Remove this line and see if it works.

Comment: It does work without height, but how could I keep it at that height and make the row fit? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you want to keep it at that **fixed** height, there's only one option: make the column wider. If there's too much content, you simply cannot fit it inside the parent with a fixed size without changing the width, height, or both.

Comment: I added overflow: auto, so I'm able to scroll the content. I also tried adding height: 280px to row, but it's still overflowing padding.

Comment: Yeah, `overflow` is another option, but then you have a vertical scrollbar. Can you please create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) snippet? It would be easier for me to help you. Put all the content instead of `...` otherwise I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the StackBlitz link to the original question.

Comment: You simply have too much content to fit it inside. I see two options: remove `height: 400px;` from the `.bg-wrapper` or reduce the content (font-sizes, paddings, margins etc.). You can also set `overflow: auto;` to the `.bg-wrapper` as you did, but I guess you don't want the content to be scrollable, otherwise you wouldn't ask for the help.

Comment: I would like the content to be srollable, just not to go over the padding of bg-wrapper.